# Setting the initial value for a radio button group in Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using the latest version of the react form library called Formik (2.1.5).

It's pretty nice, but I'm having issues with a radio button group on the initial load.

When I first load the form, I have a bunch of initial values set.

I can see them when I do a console.log and all the data is there.

My input fields and text fields load the initial values just perfectly.

But my radio button group doesn't show which radio button should be selected.

Here is my code for the radio button group:

```
<label htmlFor="radioGroup" style={{ display: "block" }}>
    Character Race
</label>
<label>
    <Field type="radio" name="charRace" value="1" />
    Human
</label>
<label>
    <Field type="radio" name="charRace" value="2" />
    Elf
</label>
<label>
    <Field type="radio" name="charRace" value="3" />
    Dwarf
</label>
```

And when the form loads, here is the initial values:

```
<Formik
    initialValues={{
        charId: id,
        charName: name,
        charClass: class,
        charRace: race
        charAge: age,
        charRegion: region
    }}
```

Now when the form loads, and the fields for charId, charName, charClass, charAge, and charRegion are all filled out properly.

And when I do a console.log for the values, I see them all...for example:

```
charId: 3728,
charName:  Jeriod,
charClass: Wizard,
charRace: 1,
charAge:  34,
charRegion: North
```

But I can't figure out how to get the charRace radio button group to have the correct radio button checked.  They are all always unchecked.

Any help would be loved , thanks!

Comment: I think if you set charRace to a string ```charRace: String(race)``` it'll work as is.

Comment: @GitGitBoom Hi, do you mean when I am setting the initialValues do to that?  Is it because it needs string values?  Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly, I just posted an answer with a sandbox you can play with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`charRace` initial value has to be a string. You can test here

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hofstadter-hihhj

```
<Formik
    initialValues={{
        charId: id,
        charName: name,
        charClass: class,
        charRace: String(race),
        charAge: age,
        charRegion: region
    }}
```

Comment: This works for Formik v.2 and doesn't for v.1

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the right strategy to adopt..

I added a '**checked**' attribute to the radio button I wanted to pre-select. Mentioning in **initialValues** within Formik alone didn't work for me.

Comment: That's correct. `initialValues` by itself doesn't work. I had to add e.g. `checked={values.myfield ==='Y'} ` in my control. Same for the "N" radio button.

Comment: after add checked attribute then I can not re-select

Comment: I am also. unable to reselect and `checked={formik.value?.gender === 'male'}` is not working

Comment: For me, upgrading to Formik v.2 fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this

1. In your main component (Formik Form or Wrapper), manage a state for your initial value
2. After you have fetched your data, update the initial state with this new fetched data. Of course making sure the data structure is the same between inital/fetched data
3. Set the initial (state value)
4. Create a Wrapper component for your Radio, RadioGroup - this is good for reusability
5. In this new component wrapper import useFormikContext hook and tap into values and setFieldValue
6. You can then set the checked property as shown in the code below and then use this component in your main formik form
7. Use the reusable RadioWrapper within formik as below

// child component
function RadioWrapper({ name, label, legend, options, ...rest }) {
const { setFieldValue, values } = useFormikContext(); //add correct type for your data
const [field, meta] = useField(name);

```
         const handlgeChane = (evt: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
             const { value } = evt.target;
             setFieldValue(name, value);
         };
       const configRadio = {
      ...field,
      ...rest,
    };

    // optional settings/configurations
    const configFormControl = { error: false };

    if (meta && meta.touched && meta.error) {
     configFormControl.error = true;
    }

   return (
     <FormControl>
       <FormLabel>{legend}</FormLabel>
       <RadioGroup onChange={handlgeChane}>
         <div style={grid === "col" ? null : colRadioGrpStyle}>
           {options.map((option) => {
             return (
               <FormControlLabel
                 {...configRadio}
                 key={option.key}
                 value={option.value}
                 control={<Radio />}
                 label={option.key}
                 checked={
                   values && option.value === values[name].value ||
                   field.value === option.value
                 }
               />
             );
           })}
         </div>
        // create configObj or pass in props as needed
           </RadioGroup {...configObj}> 
           <ErrorMessage name={name} component={ErrorText} />
         </FormControl>
       );
     })


    export default RadioWrapper;
```

Main component below

```
     const MyForm = () => {
          const = someInitialValue
          const [initialValues, setInitialVaules] = useState(someInitialValue)
          
          useEffect(() => {
             const getData = async ()=> {
              // const {data } = await axios.get(.....)
              setInitialValues(data)
             }
           
             getData()
        
          }, [])
           
          return (
            <Formik
                   initialValues={initialValues}
                   onSubmit={onSend}
                   validationSchema={validationSchema}
                   enableReinitialize={true}
                >
                   {({ setFieldValue, values }) => (
                     <Form className="......">
                        <RadioWrapper name="name" options={options} legend="something" label="some label"/>
                     </Form>
                   )}
                </Formik>
                )
        
        }
        
   export default MyForm
```