# Checkbox with Initial Value in Formik Not Toggling, Need to Handle Checked/defaultChecked

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, formik

I have a checkbox in a Formik whose initial value is determined after a DB fetch, which populates `values`. But if I do the following, then although the initial value is correct, I can't toggle the checkbox, it always remains checked.

```
<Form.Control type="checkbox" 
              id="checkCertAgreement" 
              name="certAgreement"
              checked={values.certifyAndReview === 'Y'}
              value="Y"
              onChange={handleChange} 
              onBlur={handleBlur}   
/>
```

That means I can't use `checked` but have to use `defaultChecked`. But the problem is, my `values` come after an Ajax fetch in an initial `useEffect` fetch. `defaultChecked` only applies on the **very first render**. When the first render happens, obviously `values` aren't loaded yet and `values.certifyAndReview === 'Y'` is false. So now my **initial value** for the checkboxes doesn't work anymore, although I can toggle now.

```
<Form.Control type="checkbox" 
              id="checkCertAgreement" 
              name="certAgreement"
              defaultChecked={values.certifyAndReview === 'Y'}
              value="Y"
              onChange={handleChange} 
              onBlur={handleBlur}   
/>
```

Any solutions to this?
**Note: This problem does not occur on radiobuttons, for some reason.** On radiobuttons, when I specify `checked={values.field === 'Y'}`, it both sets the initial post-fetch value and allows me to toggle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add an explicit `checked` as follows,

```
checked={values.field == 'Y' ? true : false}
```

Now it picks up initialized checked states.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Form.Check instead.

```
<Form.Check type="checkbox" 
            id="checkCertAgreement" 
            name="certAgreement"
            checked={values.certifyAndReview === 'Y'}
            onChange={handleChange} 
            onBlur={handleBlur} 
​/>
```

Comment: If you specify `checked=[anything]` you will never be able to toggle your checkbox, regardless of which specific control you use.

Comment: can you share your handleChange implementation? @geneb.

Comment: handleChange is handled by Formik. The correct way to pass Formik's handler is `{handleChange}`. It's part of `<Formik .. /> ({ handleChange, handleBlur ... })

Comment: I see. Can you try to do `onChange={e => setFieldValue('certifyAndReview', e.target.checked ? 'Y' : 'N')}`. You get `setFieldValue` from Formik. You are after e.target.checked from the event. @geneb.

Comment: I think it's setting the value correctly, but in Formik you really have to specify some kind of `checked/defautlChecked` for Formik to **initially** show a checked state, per this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67095169/1005607

Comment: found a similar question to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193822/react-bootstrap-form-check-with-formik perhaps it can help, and I see approach was same :D